# How to catch a string with re.sub but also let part of the outcome be caught again?

Tags: python, regex

I need to use Python's re.sub to catch each 'H' in a string together with its preceding letter if any and its following letter if any, in order to feed the group into re.sub's replacing function as we're gonna do magic to potentially any of these three letters.

With this example: "eHetaHḷ", I'm going to have two groups: 'eHe' and 'aHḷ', feed them into the replacing function and out shoot 'ē' and 'āl'. I can do that.

Now with this one: "eHeHḷ", I need to have two groups: 'eHe' and... 'ēHḷ', that is to say I need the outcome of the first group to be caught in the next one.

I can use only one re.sub turn and I can't catch more that one letter behind and more than one ahead. There are a considerable number of possible outcomes so I can't easily if/else my way out of this.

Have you got any brilliant idea? Am I misunderstanding Regex' way of operating completely?

Answer (score 0):

With `re.sub` you can't recursively replace on top of previous replacements.

What you can do, however, is conditionally match shorter or larger groups based on the appearance of the character `H`.

This pattern `r'\wH((?=\wH)\wH.|.)'` will match `eHe` in `eHexxx`, or `eHeH!` in `eHeH!x`.

It works by using a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=\wH)`, which matches only if the current position is followed by (word character + `H`).

So `((?=\wH)\wH.|.)` matches `(\wH.)` if `(\wH)` exists, else `(.)`.

To enable differentiated replacement rules based on the `H` count you could create a substitution function:

```py
def create_substitution(x: re.match):
    match = x.group(0)
    if match.count('H') == 1:
        return 'custom handling of match xH.'
    elif match.count('H') > 1:
        return 'custom handling of match xHxH.'
```

which you can use in your substitution:

```py
result = re.sub(r'\wH((?=\wH)\wH.|.)', create_substitution, "eHeHḷ")
```